# Is there any way to fix my mistake when setting up a Multisig wallet?

Tags: ether, wallets, multisignature, gnosis

So I am an idiot... I know. But feel free to tell me I am. 
When I set up my Multisig wallet with gnosis I made a fatal error. I created a Rinkeby Test wallet. I did a test transaction and it all worked perfectly. And then when I was setting up my main net wallet I was copy and pasting addresses and copy and pasted the wrong one... I realized this blunder a month latter when me and the other owner were trying to withdraw 1ETH we have in the wallet. Turns out I made that Rinkeby Test multisig wallet as the other owner.... ugh....

So... The wallet stats are as follows:

- Main net
- 2 owners total
- 1 owner = me
- 1 owner = a Multisig Rinkeby wallet
- everything needs 2 confirmations.

I am assuming that it is lost forever. I tried added another owner, that also, obviously, required 2 confirmations. And since the other owner wallet address is the address of a contract on the Rinkeby network, I assume there is no way to talk to the Multisig wallet on the main net. My guess is there may be someone out there on the main net, that has the same wallet address, and they could theoretically confirm my transaction. But more likely no one has a wallet with that address. Is there any way to pick your wallet address? I would guess not, but I am trying to think of any possible way of getting at this money. Uhg... I am so ashamed of myself...

Answer (score 1):

Well. As address generation works the same way in both networks and you have the necessary private keys, you can use the private keys to map to exactly the same public keys in the main net.

I didn't really follow the process of which address is the other owner, but you should be able to to figure out if you can use this feature to your advantage. Even if it is a contract address that is the second owner I believe you can generate the same contract address on the main new by using the same nonce. After that you may be able to use the contract to send the required transactions.

A bit speculative here but better than nothing! :)